# How to define gravity of a Dialog Fragment?

Tags: android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I want my dialog to stick to the start but it always comes in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will give you example==>

Following is the code -->Onclick image -->Dialog Appears==>

```
    Dialog dialog; //your dialog declaration
     // 
    //
    //
    oncreate(){


    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.customProfileGridImg);
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

    wlp.gravity = Gravity.START |Gravity.TOP; //change direction as per your requirement
    wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
    }
```